# ¿Cómo registrar asistencias sin que estas puedan duplicarse por día?

Tags: php, date, registro

tengo un pequeño problema, realizo un sistema pequeño en el cual tengo que registrar las asistencias de los profesores, pero necesito poder registrar sin que se duplique el profesores_idprofesores durante la fecha en que se registra.

```
<?php
include '../library/configServer.php';
include '../library/consulSQL.php';
$profesor=consultasSQL::clean_string($_POST['profasis']);
$fecha=consultasSQL::clean_string($_POST['fecha']);
$estado=consultasSQL::clean_string($_POST['estado']);
    if(consultasSQL::InsertSQL("asistencia", "profesores_idprofesores, fecha, estado", "'$profesor', '$fecha', '$estado'")){
        echo '<script>
            swal({
              title: "Asistencia Registrada",
              text: "El registro de asistencia del prefesor guardado",
              type: "success",
              showCancelButton: true,
              confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
              confirmButtonText: "Aceptar",
              cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
              closeOnConfirm: false,
              closeOnCancel: false
              },
              function(isConfirm) {
              if (isConfirm) {
                location.reload();
              } else {
                location.reload();
              }
            });
        </script>';
    }else{
       echo '<script>swal("ERROR", "Ocurrió un error inesperado, por favor intente nuevamente", "error");</script>';
    }
```

Este es el código del registro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí un ejemplo del problema tengo al mismo profesor registrado 2 veces en la misma fecha, cuando lo normal es que no se pueda volver a registrar en la misma fecha.
De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: pues pon un select por el id del profesor y la fecha si no encuentra agrega, si encontro algo se omite

Comment: Puedes validar que si existe ese profesor con esa fecha ingresada que no agregue en base de datos

Comment: Hay varias formas, pero para darte una respuesta real y adecuada... ¿sólo te interesa el id del profesor y la FECHA? ¿Quiero decir... guardas sólo fecha (día, mes, año), o fecha con hora de registro?

Comment: Quizás, para asegurarte la integridad de los datos en la base de datos, lo mejor seria poner un índice de tipo UNIQUE en la tabla **asistencia** con los campos fecha y profesores_idprofesores, y así, hicieras lo que hicieras en tu código, no permitiria la duplicidad dando un error (que luego deberias manejar, claro)

Comment: @VFG solo guardo la fecha sin hora